# How should repeated chords be notated in Roman numeral analysis

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, analysis, roman-numerals

In bar one, should I write chord I twice or should I write I_________
Also, in bar 3, am I right if I added chord symbols to each of the last three notes or should I add it to only one?

[image: RNA exercise]

Comment: I think your question title is more like "where to write roman numerals for a harmony analysis." I thought your question was going to be about how to select a bass and chords to support a given melody.

Answer (score 3):

1. There's no universal answer for how to write the first measure. Plenty of people (myself included) would just write `I` and not write anything else until the chord changes, the assumption being that the chord stays the same until we analyze another chord. People will also write `I    I` as you did, and as you said another possibility is `I  ----`. All are correct.
2. It's very common for chords to change quickly right before the end of a phrase. (In fancy terms, we say that "the harmonic rhythm accelerates as we approach the cadence," but don't worry if you haven't heard those terms yet; you will later!) Furthermore, your chords make complete sense there, so the end of your m. 3 looks great to me!

(Note: People typically use lowercase Roman numerals for minor chords. If that's the case, make sure you write your `II` as a `ii`. But if your teacher has asked you to use all uppercase Roman numerals, then stick with `II`!)